# Can an Egyptian visit Bahrain with a residence permit for Hungary?

Tags: visas, egyptian-citizens, bahrain

I have residence permit in Hungary and I am Egyptian passport holder. Can I visit Bahrain without a visa?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding (take it at face value: I am a random stranger off the Internet) is you need a visa.

Check http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/ this will answer precisely whether you need a visa. This is a great tool: while residence permits in general play no role in visa requirements this site will ask whether you have a residence permit. (Yes, yes, US green card holders are sometimes exempt of a certain kind of Schengen visa. Doesn't matter.)

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot.

The only people that can enter Bahrain without a visa are Bahraini and GCC nationals.

All others need a visa.  The type of visa you will need will depend on the nature of your visit.

There are three types of visas:

1. The eVisa (applied online and it is not stamped on your passport).
2. The normal on-arrival visa.
3. Visa you attain at the embassy.

Unfortunately, as an Egyptian citizen - you can only apply for a visa at the embassy.

See the [official site for evisas](https://www.evisa.gov.bh) for more information.